# Anything goes wrong with my manipulation of 'this' in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make my div whose alphabets are less than 10 invisible with Jquery, but it doesnt work, can anyone help me? THANKS!

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var $red = $('.red');
    if ($red.length<10) 
    {
        this.css("visibility","hidden")
    };
});
```

[`jsFiddel`](http://jsfiddle.net/Aw3Mu/1/)

Comment: You'll get better responses if you paste your code here rather than just linking to a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the document object inside the dom ready handler, the `if` block does not get executed in a difference execution context, it gets executed in the same context as the function in which it is included

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.red').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text()).length < 10
    }).css("visibility", "hidden");//or .hide()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2jFFZ/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate all divs with class `red` and `this` refers to  document object inside the dom ready handler. Use `$(this)` which will refer to `div` while iterating.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $red = $('.red');
    $red.each(function(){
      if ($(this).text().length<10) {
        $(this).css("visibility","hidden")
      }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/Aw3Mu/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

For what you did, `$red.length` returns how many elements were selected, not the length of the text that you want. You have to loop through them and actually get the text

http://jsfiddle.net/Aw3Mu/2/

```
<div class="red">sssssssssssssss</div>
<div class="red">ssssssssssssssssss</div>
<div class="red">sss</div>
<div class="red">sssssssssssssssssssss</div>
<div class="red">ssssss</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.red').each(function() {
           if ($(this).text().length < 10) 
               $(this).css("visibility","hidden");
        });

    });
</script>
```